# How to display the result of checked "check boxes" into one activity without leaving any blank spaces in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

i am developing a polling/voting application in Android Studio 2.0 (API 23).

The scenario:

I have a activity that shows fields(area of interest) with check-boxes below it to show that the particular field is selected.(fields here are Sports, Entertainment, Education and Technology). A button to confirm, store and redirect the user to activity/activities that he/she has selected at the check-box.

The issue:

It is not possible(or is it) to display all that is "checked" by the user in different activities displaying at the same time(that's chaos).
Or is it possible to create a format at a different activity that has text-fields(being empty) and are displayed at the run-time when the user ticks the check-box/es and use a setText() function to the blank text fields.
This will work only if the user selects the check-boxes in a sequence as it is displayed, if the user selects 1st and 3rd field, at run-time the 2nd field would be a blank area (a scroll view here is obvious).

Please provide a proper solution in detail.
Thank you.

Comment: How to increase probability of getting proper solutions in detail? - Step One: Never ask for it expressly. Step Two: Show us you did some research before asking (ideally by adding relevant code) Find out more about asking questions in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @0X0nosugar thanks, i will keep that in mind. This was my first post and i was bit confused too.

Comment: @Siddarth Raj - Confused - well, me too. If you think I sounded a bit unhappy, I admit you're right. For me, it was so unclear how much you already know and where exactly you got stuck - it's always easier to help if people show some code which is not (yet) working but which can be expanded/ improved to show them the next few steps. Thanks for answering and happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a bit confusing but as far as I have understood, you can go with this way.

Create a Shared Preference. Let user click on check boxes after click on submit button you will store the desire values as follows:

```
public class UserPreference {


SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor for Shared preferences
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// Context
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "user_preference";

public static final String isSportsCheck = "isSportsChecked";
public static final String isTechnologyCheck = "isTechnologyChecked";

 public UserPreference(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void createWork(boolean sports, boolean tech){
    editor.putBoolean(isSportsCheck, sports);
    editor.putBoolean(isTechnologyCheck, tech);
    editor.commit();
}

public HashMap<String, String> getWorkDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    user.put(isSportsCheck, pref.getBoolean(isSportsCheck, false));
    user.put(isTechnologyCheck, pref.getBoolean(isTechnologyCheck, false));

    return user;
}
```

Now in your another activity put a ScrollView in Parent, then a Linear Layout with height and width as match_parent. And then different layouts belonging to different fields like tech, sports.

Then in java class:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 HashMap<String, String> user = userPreference.getWorkDetails();
    boolean sports = user.get(userPreference.isSportsCheck);
    boolean tech = user.get(userPreference.isTechnologyCheck);

    if(sports){
          sports_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          load_sports_data();
       ..........
```

You can take this model approach and load data easily.
However you can also tab layout and then in OnResume method setup tabs based on user choice. Then in each tab use recycler view.

Comment: thank you for the solution. I totally forgot to implement "shared preferences" concept. Adding different layouts is one possible solution but i will try for a scroll view.

Comment: @SiddharthRaj it seems you're a bit confused as the question was not clear ( totally understand since you're a new) but the comment seems more confusing. Why you exactly mean by saying you will add s scroll view. Obviously you will have to add scrollview. ScrollView is just a way to give its child layout  a scroll behavior, that's it. You need to add all layout, Relative, Linear or Whatever to each content and then set visibility by getting values from Shared Preference.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is that you can store the value in String and checked status in boolean variables and make them public static.Also you can set a counter so that if any checked box is checked it gets incremented. Now in different activities let's say it activity B, you can dynamically create text boxes or text fields in your activity and intialize them by static variables and can check their checked status.